# access denied for user that has all privileges on DB

Tags: mariadb

I have a MariaDB user that is supposed to have all rights on a specific DB, as shown below

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'userX'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `DBY`.* TO `userX`@`localhost
```

I want to dump all the tables in the DB, for backup reasons. If I issue

```
mysqldump -h localhost --single-transaction -u userX DBY -p > backup.sql
```

There will be a password prompt and `backup.sql` is generated upon correct password input. Yet eventually I want `backup.sql` to be generated automatically via a cron job. So obviously I will no input the password, which is rather written at `/home/user/.my.cnf`, with the following format:

```
[DBY]
host          = localhost
user          = userX
password      = pwd
auth_plugin   = caching_sha2_password
```

So when I issue

```
mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=/home/user/.my.cnf -h localhost --single-transaction -u userX DBY > backup.sql
```

I get

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'userX'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" when trying to connect
```

`/home/user/.my.cnf` is `600` when it comes to permissions.

Can anyone spot what the issue is?

Comment: You didn't show how you created the user. Was it with the `caching_sha2_password` auth plugin? Or another plugin? Try `SHOW CREATE USER 'userX'@'localhost';`

Comment: hum, indeed I did not specify `caching_sha2_password`: `'CREATE USER 'userX'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD ''*9900B5089C982A616F8F012EC46A7BABB0D5358C'''`

Comment: What does `SELECT @@default_authentication_plugin;` return? It may be the native password plugin. If so, I guess you can fix this by changing your .my.cnf to match the plugin used for that user.

Comment: `SELECT @default_authentication_plugin;` returns `NULL`

Comment: What does `SELECT @@version;` return?

Comment: `'10.3.28-MariaDB'`

Comment: In the future please specify that you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. These are not the same product. MariaDB forked from MySQL in 2010, and both products have been changing gradually since then. There are now many cases where they are not compatible. I have edited your question's tag to make this clear.

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pluggable-authentication-overview/ says "By default, when you create a user account without specifying an authentication plugin, MariaDB uses the mysql_native_password plugin."

Comment: I see, thanks. Based on your comments I guess I should also have specified the authentication method for the user during creation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default mysqldump reads the section `[mysqldump]`. If you want to read configuration settings from another section, you have to specify the section name with `defaults-group-suffix` option:

```
mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=/home/user/.my.cnf --defaults-group-suffix=DBY -h localhost --single-transaction -u userX DBY > backup.sql
```

To avoid to read settings from other configuration files you can use `defaults-file` instead of `defaults-extra-file`.

Comment: thanks, it works, and indeed the section on my other server was `[mysqldump]`